# Regarding Snowflake Role Permissions

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, roles, privileges

I would like to know about snowflake permission settings.

"User A" has only "create user" privileges.
It also has the authority to handle objects under the database.
However, "User A" does not have the authority to handle roles such as "create role".

"User A" has "Role A" granted by the administrator. I want "user A" to be able to grant roles to other users only "role A" that he himself has been granted.

In other words, if it is a role that has been granted to yourself, I would like to set permissions so that it can be granted to other users.

Is it possible to set such permissions? Please let me know your query if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Grant role to role with grant option is not available.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-role.html#syntax

However, grant privilege to a role with a grant option is available.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-privilege.html#syntax